# Open and Read WhatsApp file with Python

Tags: python

I exported whatsapp data to my email.I would like to analyze the data with python.
How can i open and read this file?
i am using Jupyter,    .txt file
file is located in Downloads folder.

1 Import pandas as pd

2 ????

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is the format of file?

Comment: txt file  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using json data/plain text; you can read the data using the builtin `json` module.

```
import json

with open("somefile.json", "r") as f:
  file = f.read()

data = json.loads(file)

# do stuff with your new dictionary
```

If you aren't using json and are rather using a plain-text file:

```
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as f:
  file = f.read()

print(file)
# file is now a string containing your data

# turn it into a table seperated by lines:
lines = file.split("\n")
```

Hope that helped.